# Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman with heterogeneous discount rates

Tags: dynamic-programming, dynamic-optimization

Let $i=1,2$ denote the players, $x$ the state and $u_i$ the control of player $i$. The state equation reads $\dot x = f(x,u_1,u_2)$ and the objective function is given by $F_i(x,u_1,u_2)$. Now I'd like to solve the following optimal control problem of joint maximization (cooperative solution)
\begin{align}
V(x(0)) := \max_{u_1,u_2}\int^\infty_0{(e^{-r_1t}F_1(x,u_1,u_2) + e^{-r_2t}F_2(x,u_1,u_2))dt}
\end{align}

where $r_i > 0$ is the time preference rate. I was wondering how to apply the Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman in this case. Is something like the following possible?
\begin{align}
\frac{r_1+r_2}{2}V(x) = \max_{u_1,u_2}\{F_1(x,u_1,u_2) + F_2(x,u_1,u_2) + V'(x)f(x,u_1,u_2)\}
\end{align}